# How can I fetch data to dynamic List of Table in Maui from Sqlite Database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui, sqlite-net

I  want to fetch data from SQLite database in Maui using raw Query. But while trying this function I am getting error:

```
>{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
   at System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(Type type)
   at SQLite.TableMapping.GetPublicMembers(Type type)
   at SQLite.TableMapping..ctor(Type type, CreateFlags createFlags)
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.GetMapping(Type type, CreateFlags createFlags)
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[Object]()
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Query[Object](String query, Object[] args)
   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.<>c__DisplayClass83_0`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<QueryAsync>b__0(SQLiteConnectionWithLock conn)
   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<ReadAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)

 public async Task<List<dynamic>> GetItem()
    {
        var queryResult = await _db.QueryAsync<dynamic>("SELECT InvItm.*, BaseItmDet.*, FraCount FROM InvItm LEFT JOIN UnitsTb ON UnitsTb.Units = InvItm.Unit LEFT JOIN BaseItmDet ON InvItm.BaseId = BaseItmDet.BaseItemId WHERE ItemCode = '2'");
        return queryResult.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text. There's no parameter named `type` in the code you posted. The full exception text includes any inner exceptions and a stack trace that shows where the exception really came from and which function calls caused it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')'

Comment: That's not the full exception text. Post the entire text returned by `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on the `Copy Details` link in the exception popup

Comment: this is what i get when i copy details

Comment: QueryAsync<T> if i use like this , When i am using this function i may need to do like GetItem<T>(); Then what's the use . I want to dynamically fetch item .

Comment: The [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli) package has no SQLiteAsyncConnection (it doesn't need one) and almost all questions that use .Query are actually using Dapper's Query method. With Dapper, `QueryAsync(sql)` returns dynamic results. `SQLiteAsyncConnection` is part of `sqlite-net`.

Comment: [There's no support for dynamic results](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/255) in sqlite-net. I'd suggest using Microsoft's SQLite provider and [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper?tab=readme-ov-file#execute-a-query-and-map-it-to-a-list-of-dynamic-objects) to execute parameterized queries and map results